# panda dataframe to ordered dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

There is a post in which a panda dataframe is converted in to a dictionary for further processing.

The code to do this is:

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('data/file.xlsx', 'rb'), sheetname="Sheet1")
dict = df.set_index('id').T.to_dict('dict')
```

which yields something like this: `{column -> {index -> value}}`

Is there a quick way to instead of this `{column -> {index -> value}}` get this: `OrderedDict(column, value)` as a return value?

Currently, I am using the dictionary generated from pandas and assign those values in to an Ordered Dictionary, one by one. This is not the optimum way, as the order is scrambled

Example input:
An Excel file like this:

```
Unique_id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column 4
1         | 3       | 4       | 43      | 90
2         | 54      | 6       | 43      | 54
```

and the output should be an **ordered dictionary** like this:

```
{1:[3,4,43,90], 2:[54,6,43,54]}
```

Comment: what about indices ?

Comment: @MMF please explain.

Comment: `OrderedDict(column, value)` does not take into account the index. Don't want to keep it ? ?

Comment: @MMF no. Since, the column value will serve as my id. there is no point

Comment: Can you post a small DataFrame and show how the output should look like?

Comment: @ayhan Yes, check now.

Comment: Is there any reason `df.set_index('Unique_id').T.to_dict('list')` would not work?

Comment: @Abdou yes, this actually is a work-around, but not a solution to me. This approach returns a dictionary with lists as values. Problem is, dictionaries by default are **unordered**, therefore I'm losing one key aspect of the functionality that I want to have.

Comment: Well that's just one step away from what's above: `unordered_dict = df.set_index('Unique_id').T.to_dict('list'); OrderedDict((k,unordered_dict.get(k)) for k in df.Unique_id)`.

Comment: @abdou since you have already created a dictionary, the values **will be scrambled**.  This means that, when you traverse your dictionary **a second time** to store it's values in an `OrderedDict`. You will store the values in the scrambled way that they were traversed.

Comment: ***No, I does not mean that***. You are traversing your dictionary in the order you desire (here `df.Unique_id`). `k` is from the column `df.Unique_id`, which is already in the order you desire.

Comment: @Abdou Please post this as an answer so I can approve it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the dictionary in the desired order by using an `OrderedDict` with keys from the `Unique_id` column. The following should serve as an illustration:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Get the unordered dictionary
unordered_dict = df.set_index('Unique_id').T.to_dict('list')

 # Then order it
ordered_dict = OrderedDict((k,unordered_dict.get(k)) for k in df.Unique_id)
# OrderedDict([(1, [3, 4, 43, 90]), (2, [54, 6, 43, 54])])
```

Thanks!