# pandas.dataframe to orderedDictionary: using a passed argument to specify the key column name instead of explicitly writing it

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, ordereddictionary

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40995534/3551661) I want to write a function to load `csv` into `OrderedDict()`, but I don't know how to work around passing the key column name as a string instead of manually stating it? Here is my code which would make it more clear:

```
dic_key = 'uniqueID'
df.dic_key #this gives AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dic_key'
```

instead of `df.uniqueID` where `uniqueID` is the name of the column we want to use it as a key

Here is the full code:

```
def csv_to_OrderedDic1(path, dic_key='uniqueID'):
    '''

    Parameters:
        dic_key: the name of the column to be used as the dictionary key

    '''
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path, sep='\t', header=0)
    # Get an unordered dictionary
    unordered_dict = df.set_index(dic_key).T.to_dict('list')
    # Then order it
    ordered_dict = OrderedDict((k,unordered_dict.get(k)) for k in df.dic_key)
    return ordered_dict
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think better is use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and for select column `[]` instead dot notation:

```
def csv_to_OrderedDic1(path, dic_key='uniqueID'):
    '''

    Parameters:
        dic_key: the name of the column to be used as the dictionary key

    '''
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', header=0)
    # Get an unordered dictionary
    unordered_dict = df.set_index(dic_key).T.to_dict('list')
    # Then order it
    ordered_dict = OrderedDict((k,unordered_dict.get(k)) for k in df[dic_key])
    return ordered_dict
```

Another solution with `zip`and removing column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
def csv_to_OrderedDic1(path, dic_key='uniqueID'):
    '''

    Parameters:
        dic_key: the name of the column to be used as the dictionary key

    '''
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', header=0)
    L = zip(df[dic_key], df.drop(dic_key, 1).values.tolist())
    ordered_dict = OrderedDict(L)
    return ordered_dict
```