# Convert dataframe to dictionary while preserving order

Tags: python-3.7

I have a dataframe that contains two columns that I would like to convert into a dictionary to use as a map.
I have tried multiple ways of converting, but my dictionary values always comes up in the wrong order.

This is what the first few rows of my dataframe looks like:

```
geozip.head()
Out[30]: 
    Geoid    ZIP
0  100100  36276
1  100124  36310
2  100460  35005
3  100460  35062
4  100460  35214
```

I would like my dictionary to look like this:

```
{100100: 36276,
100124: 36310,
100460: 35005,
100460: 35062,
100460: 35214,...}
```

But instead my outputs came up with the wrong order for the values.

```
{100100: 98520,
 100124: 36310,
 100460: 57520,
 100484: 35540,
 100676: 19018,
 100820: 57311,
 100988: 15483,
 101132: 36861,...}
```

I tried this first but the dictionary came out unordered:

```
geozipmap = geozip.set_index('Geoid')['ZIP'].to_dict()
```

Then I tried coverting the two columns into list first then convert to dictionary, but same problem occurred:

```
geoid = geozip.Geoid.tolist()
zipcode = geozip.ZIP.tolist()
geozipmap = dict(zip(geoid, zipcode))
```

I tried converting to OrderedDict and that didn't work either. 
Then I've tried:

```
geozipmap = {k: v for k, v in zip(geoid, zipcode)}
```

Comment: dictionary type by default is unordered. have you tried with ordered dicts? https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, yes I've tried that as well and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983364/panda-dataframe-to-ordered-dictionary) ? It is the same problem you are having.

Comment: I've tried this as well and the error message I get is:

"ValueError: orient 'ZIP' not understood"

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas==0.25`, you can pass `OrderedDict` as the `into` parameter (as pointed out by @Chris Doyle. Below is an example:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

geozipmap = cityplace.set_index('Geoid')['ZIP'].to_dict(into=OrderedDict)

geozipmap

Out[1]:
OrderedDict([(100100, 36276), (100124, 36310), (100460, 35214)])
```

Comment: I think maybe because of my python version, this doesn't work for me as well.

Comment: @lee Do you happen to know which `pandas` version you are using? According to the docs even previous versions accepted it, since `pandas==0.21`

Comment: @ calestini My pandas version is 0.23.4

Comment: Weird. In [the 0.23.4 docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) they give a specific example with `Ordered Dict`, the second last example being your usecase

Comment: @ calestini I know.  I can't figure out why this isn't working.