# Dataframe to dictionary, values came out scrambled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that contains two columns that I would like to convert into a dictionary to use as a map.
I have tried multiple ways of converting, but my dictionary values always comes up in the wrong order.
My python version is 3 and Pandas version is 0.24.2.

This is what the first few rows of my dataframe looks like:

```
geozip.head()
Out[30]: 
    Geoid    ZIP
0  100100  36276
1  100124  36310
2  100460  35005
3  100460  35062
4  100460  35214
```

I would like my dictionary to look like this:

```
{100100: 36276,
100124: 36310,
100460: 35005,
100460: 35062,
100460: 35214,...}
```

But instead my outputs came up with the wrong order for the values.

```
{100100: 98520,
 100124: 36310,
 100460: 57520,
 100484: 35540,
 100676: 19018,
 100820: 57311,
 100988: 15483,
 101132: 36861,...}
```

I tried this first but the dictionary came out unordered:

```
geozipmap = geozip.set_index('Geoid')['ZIP'].to_dict()
```

Then I tried coverting the two columns into list first then convert to dictionary, but same problem occurred:

```
geoid = geozip.Geoid.tolist()
zipcode = geozip.ZIP.tolist()
geozipmap = dict(zip(geoid, zipcode))
```

I tried converting to OrderedDict and that didn't work either. 
Then I've tried:

```
geozipmap = {k: v for k, v in zip(geoid, zipcode)}
```

I've also tried:

```
geozipmap = {}
for index, g in enumerate(geoid):
    geozipmap[geoid[index]] = zipcode[index]
```

I've also tried the answers suggested:
[panda dataframe to ordered dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983364/panda-dataframe-to-ordered-dictionary)

None of these work.  Really not sure what is going on?

Comment: you can have `{100100: [36276], 100124: [36310], 100460: [35005, 35062, 35214]}` this format but i don't think so the format you want with same key in dict is possible

Comment: `df.to_dict('records')` will give you something like this `[{'Geoid': 100100, 'ZIP': 36276},
 {'Geoid': 100124, 'ZIP': 36310},
 {'Geoid': 100460, 'ZIP': 35005},
 {'Geoid': 100460, 'ZIP': 35062},
 {'Geoid': 100460, 'ZIP': 35214}]`

Comment: @Lee the issue is same key pointing to different values

Comment: @tawab_shakeel Thank you!  It was so obvious but I didn't realize that I was trying to map same keys to different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `default_dict` and if same `key` have multiple values you can provide those as list

```
from collections import defaultdict

df =pd.DataFrame(data={"Geoid":[100100,100124,100460,100460,100460],
                   "ZIP":[36276,36310,35005,35062,35214]})
data_dict = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in zip(df['Geoid'],df['ZIP']):
   data_dict[k].append(v)

print(data_dict)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {100100: [36276], 100124: [36310], 100460: [35005, 35062, 35214]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
dfG = df['Geoid'].values
dfZ = df['ZIP'].values
for g , z in zip (dfG,dfZ):
    print(str(g)+':'+str(z))
```

This gives the output as below (but the values are strings)

```html
100100:36276
100124:36310
100460:35005
100460:35062
100460:35214
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  The weird thing is when I'm iterating the two lists, it comes out in the right order.  The problem is when I try to append that to a dictionary, that it comes out scrambled.

Comment: when i try `df.to_dict('records')` or `df.to_dict('series')`, it is coming in proper order

Comment: I realized that I'm trying to map many of the same keys to different values, that's why it looked like it wasn't in the right order.